# Download a file from Internet Explorer without giving a dialog box

Tags: javascript, vb.net, internet-explorer

I need some help regarding file downloading files from Internet Explorer from Javascript but I want the file to get downloaded by itself and don't want the dialog box to ask where to save the file.

If it can be done via VB.Net that is not an issue.

Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: Well, first you need to make your own browser... YOU CAN'T. That is part of IE, although why you are still using IE only God knows why. You can't change what the browser does.

Comment: Actually we are using 3 Browsers But my end users want the same functionality on every Browser. Chrome and Firefox are fine but users want same thing in IE

Comment: You don't control the browser. The browser decided what kind of UI to use. The best you can do is try to download it in the background, but all browsers will probably block that. There is no way to do this.